# Select words of string up to particular word and eleminate the words comes after that

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I had a text input in the following format ,

contact details Details

Customer Name :

eswar

Requirement :

Smart Card Printing Machine Dealers

customer Phone :

+XXXXXXXXXXX

For any queries, please feel free to call our Customer Support Division

on ph.No XXX-XXXXXXXXXX and speak to Customer Support Executive

My task is to extract the **Customer Name :**,**Requirement :** etc from it and store it to the database. i am using the following code for this execution:

```
dim Customer as string
s = (s.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ",").Replace(",,", "")) 'replace enter with         comas to create a single string
content_array = s.Split(",") 'split the string into array  
Customer= find_content("Customer Name :", 16)
Public Function find_content(ByVal sub_str As String, ByVal position As Integer) As String
   Dim result As String
   result = ""
   For i As Integer = 0 To content_array.Length
     If content_array(i) = "" Then
       content_array(i) = "default value"
     Else
       result = Trim(content_array(i).Substring(content_array(i).IndexOf(sub_str) + position))
     End If
      i = i + 1
   Next
Return result
End Function
```

Now my problem is that insertion of null values in the array creating problem in function, and result in errors. Please suggest solutions for **avoiding null value (" ") insertion to the array while performing split**. or an **alternative method for extracting the details** as mentioned. or Extracting the following content as mentioned from the string, "For any queries **please feel free to call** our Customer Support Division

Comment: Wouldn't solve all your problems if use a field for each value? I supose there's a reason to have all values in the same field, but I have to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim s as string' be your input
dim content_array() as string
Dim customer_name As String
Dim customer_requirement As String
Dim customer_phon As String
s = (s.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ",").Replace(",,", "")) 'replace enter with comas to create a single string
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("For any queries"))'eliminate string after "For any queries"
content_array = s.Split(",") 'split the string into array                
For i As Integer For i As Integer = 1 To content_array.Length
If content_array(i) <> "" Then
find_content(content_array(i))'function call
End If
Next
```

create a database connection and insert the values; the following function will give you the required values

```
Public Sub find_content(ByVal find_string As String)
Dim result() As String
result = find_string.Split(":")
If Trim(result(0).ToString) = "Caller Name" Then
customer_name = result(1).ToString
ElseIf Trim(result(0).ToString) = "Caller Requirement" Then
customer_requirement = result(1).ToString
ElseIf Trim(result(0).ToString) = "Caller Phone" Then
customer_phon = result(1).ToString
End If
End Sub
```

hope that this is actualy you are looking for